# CM install CDH4(hadoop2.0) ,don't put file into fdfs

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

```
# #sudo -u hdfs hadoop -mkdir test
# #sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /root/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/share/hadoop/mapreduce/word.txt    test
put: `/root/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/share/hadoop/mapreduce/word.txt': No such file or directory

I am sure the file word.txt is there!  

And I browse hdfs from CM web UI http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:7180/cmf/services/25/hdfs/browse  
got Reports Manager () the connection is unavailable or unresponsive.
What is the problem? can any one help? pleases! Thanks in advance!
```

I run :

```
#sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls -R /
.........<hr />
.....<hr />
```

> drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs  supergroup          0 2013-06-06 23:40 /tmp
>
> ---
>
> drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-07        09:58 /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files
>
> ---
>
> drwxr-xr-x   - mapred supergroup          0 2013-06-06 14:46 /tmp/mapred
>
> ---
>
> drwx------   - mapred supergroup          0 2013-06-06 16:36 /tmp/mapred/system
>
> ---
>
> -rw-------   3 mapred supergroup          4 2013-06-06     16:36 /tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info
>
> ---
>
> drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 17:12 /user
>
> ---
>
> drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 22:59 /user/hdfs
>
> ---
>
> drwx------   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-07 08:00 /user/hdfs/.Trash
>
> ---
>
> drwx------   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06    23:40 /user/hdfs/.Trash/130607080000
>
> ---
>
> drwx------   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 23:40 /user/hdfs/.Trash/130607080000/tmp
>
> ---
>
> drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 23:39 /user/hdfs/.Trash/130607080000/tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files
>
> ---
>
> drwx------   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 22:58 /user/hdfs/.Trash/130607080000/user
>
> ---
>
> drwx------   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 22:58 /user/hdfs/.Trash/130607080000/user/hdfs
>
> ---
>
> drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 17:12 /user/hdfs/.Trash/130607080000/user/hdfs/test
>
> ---
>
> drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   supergroup          0 2013-06-06 22:59 /user/hdfs/test
>
> ---
>
> .....................
>
> ---
>
> ........
>
> ---

```
>The log hdfs i got is:

2013-06-07 10:00:51,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR*    completeFile: /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2013_06_07-10_00_51 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_57683786_107
2013-06-07 10:00:51,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 91 Total time for transactions(ms): 4Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 46 SyncTimes(ms): 306
2013-06-07 10:00:51,262 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addToInvalidates: blk_-7087383405853393980_3513 192.168.93.85:50010 192.168.93.108:50010 192.168.93.86:50010
2013-06-07 10:00:52,511 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* InvalidateBlocks: ask 192.168.93.108:50010 to delete [blk_-7087383405853393980_3513]
2013-06-07 10:00:55,511 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* InvalidateBlocks: ask 192.168.93.86:50010 to delete [blk_-7087383405853393980_3513]
2013-06-07 10:00:58,511 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* InvalidateBlocks: ask 192.168.93.85:50010 to delete [blk_-7087383405853393980_3513]
```

Comment: Please update your post with an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your hdfs user has permission to read

/root/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/share/hadoop/mapreduce/word.txt

Go to

/root/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/share/hadoop/mapreduce/

Do

ls -l

Check what is permission of word.txt

Make it 777 and then try again

Comment: hello ,user2230605,I do it what you talk,but it failed also. root@chuntent85 mapreduce]# chmod 777 word.txt [root@chuntent85 mapreduce]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /root/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/share/hadoop/mapreduce/word.txt test put: `/root/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/share/hadoop/mapreduce/word.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: well,thanks user2230605,I got it `it is the permition problem ,I  run hadoop with hdfs,but the file in root directory,so it failed.I copy the file to /tmp and it work fine now! `